# Facebook Login for Web

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, login-script

According to this link [Facebook Login for the Web](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4), I can let my users login with facebook accounts (after logging to my facebook app).

now, all the work is done here in javascript which is a client-based code, it means it is insecure and a hacker could easily trespass my login step.

I know i should be using PHP SDK (for example) to secure the login process, but my question is why would I use this method ????

Comment: You should used a good SSL Certificate to encrypt your site traffic.  That should help deter hackers.

Comment: @jradich1234 okay of course SSL Certificate is recommended. Im just asking about the logic behind logging in from the client script